# Reloading Core Data Table View From Another Class

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview, core-data

I am trying to refresh the data on a tableview that is using core data on a view controller (View Controller 1). The save button (UIButton) which is used to save the values into core data is on a different view controller (View Controller 2).

They are both on the same screen on the iPad at the same time but have separate classes (header and main files) by using Container Views. When I click the save button on the View Controller 1, it does not refresh the table view which is on the View Controller 2.

However, I know that it is not the way it is saving the data into Core Data because when I refresh the application, the new cell pops up on the table view like it's supposed to. I have tried the following ways to try and get the table view to refresh with no luck:

```
// ViewController1.m (Save Button)

- (IBAction)saveMethod {

    //Core Data Save Method Goes Here (Irrelevant)

    [self.managedObjectContext save:nil];

    //ViewController2 has the table view
    ViewController2 *trackingView = [[ViewController2 alloc] init];

    trackingView.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
    [trackingView setupFetchedResultsController];
    [trackingView.view setNeedsDisplay];
    [trackingView.table reloadData];
}
```

I cannot seem to figure out how to tell this table view to refresh itself from a different View Controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to recreate the viewcontroller as you are doing now.

When the `NSManagedObjectContext` completes a save operation, it posts a notification. You can have any object register to receive these notifications. Consider this if re-setting the delegate of the `fetchedResultsController` would not be an option (i.e. `ViewController1` is already set as the delegate, and it makes sense for `ViewController1` to continue acting as the delegate).

`ViewController2` will need a reference to the managed object context that is handling your data, so you would want to create a property and set it appropriately (`@property NSManagedObjectContext *moc`).

Then, in `viewDidLoad` it can [register for notifications](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObjectContext_Class/NSManagedObjectContext.html):

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(handleNotification:)
                                             name:NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification
                                           object:self.moc];
```

`ViewController2` will have to define a method `handleNotification:`:

```
-(void)handleNotification:(NSNotification*)notification {
    if ( [notification.name isEqual:NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification] && [notification.object isEqual:self.moc] ) {
        [self.tableView reloadData];
    }
}
```

A couple notes about this approach:

1. When you view controller has been dismissed, make sure to call `[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self]`. The notification center retain observers (I found out the hard way once).
2. Always include the managed object context when registering for notifications, you don't want be responding to every save notification.

Comment: I tried the following above. Seems like it should've worked but it didn't. Do I need to create another property if in the View Controller  2 I already have a managedObjectContext property? Because I tried it by adding rather than "self.moc" i did "self.managedObjectContext" and that did not work

Comment: You shouldn't need to create another property, and the actual naming doesn't matter. As long `managedObjectContext` in both view controllers point to same object.

Comment: Yeah that's what I figured. Both managedObjectContext are pointing to the App Delegate

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't want to create a new instance of `ViewController2` when your goal is for the instance you already have to refresh. In fact, your problem is in `ViewController2`, not here.

Make sure `ViewController2` is set as the delegate of its fetched results controller, and then update your table view from the fetched results controller delegate callbacks. And make sure both view controllers are looking at the same managed object context.

Comment: Can you explain to me how I would use it by setting it up as a delegate?

Comment: Did you read the documentation for `NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate`? There's nearly a one-to-one mapping between the callbacks you get and the update methods on `UITableView`.